Classical tilting theory phrased in terms of Koszul duality
Let $C$ be a stable category and $P \in C$. We can consider $\langle P \rangle$, the category generated by $P$ under retracts and finite colimits.
Then koszul duality tells us that $\langle P \rangle = Mod(End(P))$ where $End$ is taken in the derived sense, and $Mod$ means the derived category of modules (probably "DG modules").
I would like help to deduce from this fact all the standard tilting theorems, or understand the relationship with them. I bolded subquestions.
Classically, we have for a finite dimensional algebra $A$ and its derived category of modules:
A tilting module is such that

$pdim(P) \leq 1$
$Ext^1(P,P)=0$
There is a short-exact sequence $ A \to P_1 \to P_2 $ where $P_i \in add(P)$, where $add(P)$ is direct sums of direct summands.

In this case, $D^b(A) = D^b(End(P))$
From 1,2 we deduce that $End(P)$ is really nonderived, and from 3 we deduce $M$ generates everything.
1. Why don't we just require $End(P)$ is underived vs conditions 1,2?
2. Why do we require such an efficient presentation of $A$ in condition 3?
** A generalized tilting module **

Finite projective dimension
$End(P)$ is underived (i.e higher ext vanish)
$A \in \langle P \rangle$

3. Is this one literally, exactly, koszul duality?

In condition 3, what is $A$?

@KentaS I edited; it's the ring whose modules we take.

Sorry and what is $T$?

@KentaS Thank you fixed that too!
